# How to handle Craft 3 events in a plugin? Element API is returning null data

Tags: plugin-elementapi, events, craft3

The below refers to Craft 3 and the Element API plugin for Craft 3.

I would like to do something when the Element API plugin fires its `onBeforeSendData` event, I can see in the controller for element there is this:

```
$this->trigger(self::EVENT_BEFORE_SEND_DATA, new DataEvent([
    'data' => $data,
]));
```

And based on Craft 3 docs and Yii 2 docs I think I would use the following in my plugins init function:

```
Event::on(ElementController::class, ElementController::EVENT_BEFORE_SEND_DATA, function(DataEvent $event) {
    var_dump($event->data);
}
```

I would have expected that to return a `League\Fractal\Scope` object but instead I am just getting `null`. Have I implemented this correctly?

Interestingly while trying to work out where I went wrong, if I modify the Element API DefaultController class and change the `data` property in the trigger to `eventData` and add the new public property to the `DataEvent` class then it all works and I am able to see the data in my plugin.